# AppendHeader doesn't add to HttpResponseBase.Headers collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, moq, httpresponse

I'm stuck writing a unit test for a custom ActionFilter in ASP.NET MVC.

Everything works fine but I'm having a strange behavior in my unit test. [`AppendHeader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendheader.aspx) seems not to modify the `HttpResponseBase.Headers` collection. When I debug the following code, I have only two items in my collection: `"A"` and `"C"`.

```
var responseStub = new Moq.Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
responseStub.Setup(r => r.Headers)
    .Returns(new WebHeaderCollection { { "A", "A" } });

var response = responseStub.Object;

response.AppendHeader("B", "B");
response.Headers.Add(new NameValueCollection { { "C", "C" } });
```

Can somebody shed some light on this and explain why this is behaving like that?

If I run the Website using `AppendHeader` in my ActionFilter I'm getting the header. So it generally works, but as I said, I'm missing it in my `HttpResponseBase.Headers` collection for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of the `HttpResponseBase.AppendHeader` method that you are trying to invoke it is actually not surprising that this method does nothing.

```
public virtual void AppendHeader(string name, string value)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

If you want this method to do something you have to define an expectation for that:

```
// arrange
var responseStub = new Moq.Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
responseStub.Setup(r => r.Headers)
    .Returns(new WebHeaderCollection { { "A", "A" } });
var response = responseStub.Object;
responseStub
    .Setup(r => r.AppendHeader(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Callback<string, string>((name, value) => response.Headers.Add(new NameValueCollection { { name, value } }));

// act
response.AppendHeader("B", "B");

// assert
Assert.AreEqual(2, response.Headers.Count);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Anyhow I think for testing purpose I'm better of changing the implementation in my action filter from `AppendHeader` to `Headers.Add`.